# Determining if Firebase didn't download data with startAt and endAT

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to download data with Firebase. The issue is that I'm downloading the data based off of a timestamp. If their is only one item in my `ListView` that I'm populating, I want to get the next two hours worth of data from Firebase and if there isn't any data from the last two hours, I want to get the next two hours of data and so on until I get some additional data. The issue is that I don't exactly know how to determine if Firebase actually downloaded data. Because if data was downloaded, I can use an `OnScrollListener` for my `listView` to download more data since it will be scrollable after that point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot know when getting the data from the database is completed becase `Firebase is a real-time database` and getting data might never complete. That's why is named a realtime database because in any momemnt the database can be changed, items can be added or deleted.

The only way to partially know if you have all the data at a particular location is to perform a single 'value' type query on it. Even then, the data may change after that listener is invoked, so all you really have is a `snapshot` at a particular moment in time.

You can use a `CompletionListener` only when you **write** or **update** data in your database and you'll be notified when the operation has been acknowledged by the Firebase servers but you cannot use this interface when reading data.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to know if the download is completed, because like you said, it is never completed. I just want to know IF something is downloaded.

Comment: This is what I was trying to say, you cannot know when or if is completed, due it's realtime behaviour.

Comment: Hmmmm okay. I guess I have to go back to checking the ListView itself to see how many elements it has.

Comment: You can know when a value is written or updated in the database for sure by adding a CompletionListener. In this case, as I said, in any moment the database can be changed.