# How to read all children of a Firebase node and monitor changes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to read all children of a node and then keep track of any changes that happen after that. One use case might be a local cache where I want to hold off using the cache until I know it's populated.

The one way I could imagine doing that is by first calling `Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` to get the initial state. After I get the result, I know my local cache is populated, and I can now call `Query.addChildEventListener()` to get updates on when children are added and removed.

However, this seems inefficient - now the entire list of children is being sent across the wire twice, and I need to add a check to skip entries coming from `addChildEventListener()` that I already got from `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`.

It's not that big of a deal, but I wonder if there's a better way - isn't there a way to simply call `addChildEventListener()` and get a signal when all entries have been sent?

Comment: Using onchildAdd instead, ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added

Comment: You should only have to add `addChildEventListener`. Its `onChildAdded` will immediately be called for any existing child nodes on the location.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's right, but how do I know when I have the complete list of all the children? I don't want to use my local cache until I know that it's populated.

Comment: You cannot know when you have the complete list of all the children. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532768/determining-if-firebase-didnt-download-data-with-startat-and-endat/48537436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To both start synchronizing data *and* know when the initial synchronization has finished, you will need to add two listeners.

1. a `ChildEventListener` to handle the actual updates.
2. a `ValueEventListener` to detect when a complete update has been sent.

For the initial data from the database, your `ChildEventListener.onChildAdded` will be called first for each child node. After that the `ValueEventListener.onDataChange` will be called.

So as soon as `onDataChange` gets called, you can know that all initial data has loaded. If you only care about this initial data being complete, you can register this listener with `addSingleValueEventListener` so that it detaches after the initial synchronization.

Note that Firebase transfers data only once, even when there are multiple listeners for that data. So if you attach both listeners to the same location, the data will only be read once.